# Sample the neighbour value from a list

Tags: python, list, random, sample

Let say, I have a list:

```
[Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]
```

and I randomly choose the index (let say idx=4, thus "May"), I want my function to return

```
[Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul]
```

If the index is 0 (Jan) or 1 (Feb) then I want my function to return `[Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May]`. 
The length of returned list is always 5.

How to create such function in Python3?

Simple question but why my head starts to explode?

Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth my question got dislike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
monthes = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

def myfunc(choices, index):
    start = min(max(index - 2, 0), len(choices) - 5)
    return choices[start:start+5]

print(myfunc(monthes, 4))
print(myfunc(monthes, 0))
print(myfunc(monthes, 1))
```

Comment: If `idx=11` it returns [Oct, Nov, Dec]. How to return [Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec] ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if index<=2 or :
   print(list[:5])
elif index>=len(list)-2:
   print(list[-5:])
else:
   print(list[index-2:index+2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# List of months
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
# Get input
index = int(input())

def getMonths(index):
  if index>1 and index<len(months)-2:
    # Return 5 elements in the neighbourhood of the index
    return months[index-2:index] + months[index:index+3]
  elif index<=1 and index>=0: 
    # Return first 5 if index less than 2
    return months[:5]
  elif index>len(months)-2:
    # Return last 5 elements if index greater
    return months[len(months)-5:]
  else:
    # Return -1 for invalid index
    return -1
# Print output
print(getMonths(index))
```